# Merge cells of text using filter and dynamic array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

In the same way of my question about the double value [Remove double values and sum the values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76714682/2262011), I need to concatenate textual value in function a filter value, let see the table :

[image]

And I want this table :

[image]

I'm using dynamic array, and I want that the output formula are also dynamic array.

Now, the only formula that I can get is this one:

[fr]

```
 =JOINDRE.TEXTE("/";VRAI;CHOISIRCOLS(FILTRE(B1#;PRENDRE(B1#;;1)=H1);2))
```

[en]

```
=TEXTJOIN("/", TRUE, CHOOSECOLS( FILTER( B1#, TAKE( B1#,,1) = H1),2))
```

But, I want to replace H1 by H1# but it doesn't work.

What is the best way to get it ? Thank's

Comment: If you have access to `GROUPBY()` you can do this quite easily. Otherwise you'd need to loop your range using `MAP()` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following formula :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, B2:B11,
     b, C2:C11,
     ua, UNIQUE(a),
     HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ua)),ua, BYROW(ua, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTER(b,a=x))))))
```

---

Or, with `GROUPBY()` applicable to `MS365` Beta Channel Version for now:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     a, GROUPBY(B1:B11,C1:C11,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0),
     HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),a))
```

---